# $h^0(S^nF(nD_1+D_2))=O(n^2)$ for a rank 2 vector bundle $F$ on a smooth curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

The following proposition and proof are given in Lemma 2.5 of https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1272710, and I have some questions about it.

**Proposition.** Let $F$ be a rank 2 vector bundle on a smooth curve $C$, and $D_1,D_2$ divisors on $C$. Then $h^0(S^nF(nD_1+D_2))=O(n^2)$. (Here $n$ is a positive integer and $S^nF$ is the $n$-th symmetric product.)

Proof) Choose $D_3$ effective with $D_3\geq D_2$. Then $S^nF(nD_1+D_2)\subset S^nF(n(D_1+D_3))=S^n(F(D_1+D_3))$. So assume $D_1=D_2=0$, and $F$ very positive. Now use Riemann-Roch.

The proof is very short, but I cannot understand most of it.

1. How do we have $S^nF(nD_1+D_2)= (S^nF)\otimes O(nD_1+D_2)\subset (S^nF)\otimes O(n(D_1+D_3))= S^nF(n(D_1+D_3))$?
2. From 1, why can we assume $D_1=D_2=0$?
3. What is the definition of "very positive"? I cannot find it in the paper or google.
4. How does Riemann-Roch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) finish the proof?

Comment: Your link is not freely accessible, which makes some of this hard to answer, but I can say a few things. Your first question is ultimately a consequence of $\mathcal O_C(D_2) \subset \mathcal O_C(D_3)$, itself basically by definition from the inequality. The term "very positive" is presumably not precise; the point is that sufficiently positive vector bundles tend to have large $h^0$ but $h^i = 0$ for $i > 0$. This means then that $\chi(L) = h^0$, so Riemann-Roch computes $h^0$ directly...

Comment: ...By the way, you will need RR for vector bundles on a curve, not the version in the Wikipedia article. I think the main point is that you have a degree-times-rank term, and assuming that the rank of symmetric powers is linear in $n$ (I don't remember this off hand) you are basically there.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks. Why $O(D_2)\subset O(D_3)$ is a consequence of $D_3\geq D_2$? What I know about the definition of $O(D)$ is : for a divisor $D=\sum_i a_iY_i$ on a complex manifold $X$, there is an open cover $X=\cup_j U_j$ such that $U_j\cap Y_i$ is the zero set of a holomorphic function $g_{ij}$ on $U_j$. Put $f_j=\prod_i g_{ij}^{a_i}$. Then the functions $\{f_j\cdot f_k^{-1}\}$ satisfy the cocycle condition and define a line bundle $O(D)$.

Comment: This is fairly basic material that you should probably read about in e.g. Griffiths-Harris or Miranda.